# gradlew stuck at listening for transport dt_socket

Tags: gradle, gradlew

On cmd, all gradle commands like "gradlew, gradlew -version, gradlew build" get stuck with one line

`Listening for transport dt_socket at address:5006`

Comment: Is is at the beginning of the logs? Can you go through the properties files/environment variables described in [this documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html).

Comment: Are you trying to debug something ? 5005 is usually used for debugging

Comment: Actually it's 5006

Comment: The solution was to delete GRADLE_OPTS system environment variable

Answer (score 2):

Most probably, your Gradle runs in debug mode. Debug can be turned on in different ways. Check the value of `GRADLE_OPTS` environment variable and `org.gradle.jvmargs` Java system property. Latter can be set in different places: on the project level (in `gradle.properties` in project root) or in global config (`~/.gradle/gradle.properties`).

Setting `suspend` to `n` will allow you to both run the process in debug mode and do not wait for the debugger.